# @XmlAnyElement and @XmlElementRefs

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, eclipselink, moxy

I use following annotated class for unmarshalling with MOXy 2.4.0. Unmarshalling into this object works just fine

```
@XmlElementRefs({
        @XmlElementRef(name = "a", namespace = "http://mynamespace", type = JAXBElement.class),
        @XmlElementRef(name = "b", namespace = "http://mynamespace", type = JAXBElement.class)
})
protected List<JAXBElement<?>> elements;
```

i now want to allow arbitrary elements in this list, so I attached `@XmlAnyElement`

```
@XmlAnyElement(lax=true)
@XmlElementRefs({
        @XmlElementRef(name = "a", namespace = "http://mynamespace", type = JAXBElement.class),
        @XmlElementRef(name = "b", namespace = "http://mynamespace", type = JAXBElement.class)
})
protected List<Object> elements;
```

Now the whole list contains only classes of type `com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.dom.ElementNSImpl` but shouldn't `lax=true` enable a heterogeneous list of either DOM-Elements and JAXBElements in this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a known issue in [**EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy)**](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/moxy.php).  You can use the following bug to track our progress on this issue:

- http://bugs.eclipse.org/401103

Comment: just in case, if someone with the same problem stumbles upon this answer: my current workaround for this problem is to split known and unknown elements into two attributes, so i dont have the problem mentioned above at all.